# Is it common to have period as a separate model/table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am trying to refactor a half finished project. Original developer has left. In his model design, a separate "period" model is used. So a discount object has a *usable period* and event can have a *period*.

The periods table:

```
  create_table "periods", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "owner_type"
    t.datetime "begin"
    t.datetime "end"
    t.datetime "created_at",                               :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               :null => false
  end
```

I am starting to feel difficult writing listing queries based on dates. I need to join the period table and sort on that end date field.

What I want to ask is: what are the pros/cons of this approach? I am feeling that moving those back to the belonging models makes more sense.

Comment: It basically comes down to multiplicity.

Comment: If you know that the case is that you need to join the tables to get a period, it makes fine sense. The main thing is not how people do, but that they teach their heirs about it.

Comment: If you are ever in a situation where you need to know *everything* that happened within a given time frame, say everything that happen in June, it makes perfect sense that the period is in a separate table. =)

Comment: Here you are. One answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a `period` table is not necessarily a strange practice: As long as that kind of information is delivered to the project developer's heir.

And in a case where you would want to know about *everything* that happened in a given time period, say June, that devision of tables makes perfect sense.

So my point is that I guess it's about communication and needs. If you don't need that functionality anymore, I suggest a migration that adds two new columns to all polymorphic tables related to the periods, `begins_at` and `ends_at` and then migrates all the data from the periods table into those respect columns.